# Change icon for .bin file

Tags: icons

I have downloaded SQLite Studio .bin file. After I made it executable and start it, icon is pretty disappointing. Because of that, I got another .png icon from the web. Changing icon in properties of .bin file works, but only temporary, when app is started, there's still same ugly icon in Unity and ALT+TAB window. Even creating Application Entry in ./local/share/applications/sqlitestudio.desktop with icon path to /opt/sqlitestudio/icon.png doesn't work... I find it in Unity search, icon is good there, but again, after starting application, same old ico. What can I do? 
It's Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks

Comment: In this case, icon is stored inside of .bin file, that's why app doesn't use my custom icon. I'm in doubt how to edit .bin file to remove default icon, if that is possible, ofc.

Comment: You can't edit the .bin. And it's irrelevant. You need to put `StartupWMClass=Sqlitestudio-2.1.5.bin` in your `sqlitestudio.desktop` file, as per following the instructions, in the answer, of that duplicate question.

Comment: I had no idea how xprop thing work. I made it work now, thank you so much!